# For a git repo, how do I generate a list of commit, total lines of code in app, date of commit?

Tags: git

How do I generate a csv with the following data for a git repo?

```
commit_id, loc_app, loc_commit (optional), date
```

PR_id would work a little better but not sure if that is tougher. Why would anyone want this? I'm trying to graph loc per unit time obviously. The app I am working in is more duplicated code than feature code, you wouldn't believe it. 200,000 lines of code, ~10,000 of it is needed once dedupped. I would like to track progress less than manually.

Much appreciated.

Comment: Split the task into smaller steps. First, [count lines](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+count+lines) in one commit. Then run a loop over call commits.